# What conditions will trigger popup blocker?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know the conditions which will trigger popup blocker.
I know that window.open without user clicking the page will trigger the popup blocker.
But if the user clicks on the flash and then the flash calls the window.open js function, will this trigger the popup blocker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [What triggers "popup blocker"?](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/504498-what-triggers-popup-blocker)

> Unfortantly the answer for that is,
>   "Whatever the programmer(s) of the
>   popup blocker wanted it to be
>   triggered by." This can very widely
>   from one popup blocker to another.
>   Many are triggered by any javascript
>   that generates a new window without
>   any user interaction. Some are even
>   more restrictive then that.